# Save data to json file use angular js and asp.net mvc actions

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs

I have tried to save data to json file using angular js $http post to asp.net controller

Here is my codes

view with angular js

```
 var postdata =
                             {

                                 Email: "test1@gmail.com",
                                 selectedanswers: jsonArr
                             };
        $http({
            url: "/page/PostFileWithData",
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
            },
            method: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            traditional: true,
            data: JSON.stringify(postdata)
        }).success(function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }).error(function (data) {
            console.log('fail');
        });
```

Modal is asp.net c#

```
public class UserModel
    {

        public string Email { get; set; }
        //public string selectedanswers { get; set; }
        //public Dictionary<int, int> selectedanswers { get; set; }

        //public List<selectedanswersModel> selectedanswers { get; set; }
        public List<Answer> selectedanswers { set; get; }

    }


    public class Answer
    {

        public int AnswerId { set; get; }
    }
```

Controller in asp.net

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult PostFileWithData(UserModel userdata)
    {


        UserModel udata = new UserModel
        {
            Email = userdata.Email,
            selectedanswers = userdata.selectedanswers
        };

        var json = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/data.json"));


          JArray array = JArray.Parse(json);
          var itemToAdd = new JObject();
          itemToAdd["Email"] = userdata.Email;
          itemToAdd["selectedanswers"] = userdata.selectedanswers;  
          array.Add(itemToAdd);

          var jsonToOutput = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(array, Formatting.Indented);

          System.IO.File.WriteAllText(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/data.json"), jsonToOutput);




        return Json(udata, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);


    }
```

My problem is in controller action JsonResult which at where i wanted to save posted data to data.json file 
this only storing Email data but not selected answers regarding this

```
itemToAdd["selectedanswers"] = userdata.selectedanswers;
```

this line of code to store at the index, i am getting error in this line 
so selectedanswers not storing to json file, i am receiving this data at console.log

here is my console.log result

```
[console result][1]
```

Can you please help me? 
Thanks

Comment: what are you getting in `userdata.selectedanswers` on serverside

Comment: its giving me selected data like this

0
:
{AnswerId: 3}
1
:
{AnswerId: 2}
2
:
{AnswerId: 0}
3
:
{AnswerId: 3}
4
:
{AnswerId: 2}
5
:
{AnswerId: 3}
6
:
{AnswerId: 1}
7
:
{AnswerId: 3}
8
:
{AnswerId: 2}
9
:
{AnswerId: 0}
10
:
{AnswerId: 3}
11
:
{AnswerId: 2}
12
:
{AnswerId: 0}

Comment: can you write like this  `itemToAdd["selectedanswers"] = userdata.selectedanswers.select(a=> a.AnswerId).ToArray();`

Comment: I have tried this, but showing another error at Select

Comment: what is error, you are getting

Comment: Here is the link of screenshot https://ibb.co/mvAmB7

Comment: do like this  itemToAdd["selectedanswers"] =JArray.FromObject(userdata.selectedanswers.select(a=> a.AnswerId).ToArray());

Comment: super @PranayRana its working but can do me a more favor this?saving to json file like this https://ibb.co/kUPzyn
I want like this
https://ibb.co/iK0uW7

Comment: updated my answer , can you try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try like this

```
itemToAdd["selectedanswers"] 
     =JArray.FromObject(userdata.selectedanswers.select(a=> a.AnswerId).ToArray());
```

or try this

```
itemToAdd["selectedanswers"] 
     =JArray.FromObject(userdata.selectedanswers.select(a=> 
 new { AnswerId = a.AnswerId } ).ToArray());
```

Comment: Supper @pranay Rana, it working like a charm, you are very helpful

Comment: hi @pranay rana can you please help me for this question?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50213054/angular-js-cookies-put-is-not-working

Comment: @MohammadSumon - i work on angular 2 and .net stuff not have much knowledge on angularjs , apologies