# Angular js $cookies.put is not working

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to use  $cookies.put function in my application but this not working here is my code of controller

```
var app = angular.module('allianze');

app.controller('quizctrl', QuizCtrl);

QuizCtrl.$inject = ['QuizData', 'quizMetrics', '$http', '$filter'];


function QuizCtrl(QuizData, quizMetrics, $http, $filter, $cookies, $window, 
$cookieStore) 
{
     var now = new Date(),

     exp = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth() + 6, now.getDate());
     $cookies.put('quiztaken', 'yes', {
                expires: exp
            });
}
```

this showing me error like this

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'put' of undefined
```

can you please help me

Comment: Inject $cookies, $window & $cookieStore in QuizCtrl.$inject = [....] also

Comment: @aman Srivastava, I have injected it like this 

QuizCtrl.$inject = ['QuizData', 'quizMetrics', '$http', '$filter', '$cookies', '$window', '$cookieStore'];

but getting another error

Error: [$injector:unpr]

Comment: verify your steps from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10961963/how-to-access-cookies-in-angularjs